# Get Unique Value from array in Php

Tags: php, arrays

i need to get unique values from array , the input is

```
$item = $_GET['table_id'];              

$table_id = explode(",",$item);             
$table_count = count($table_id);            

for($i=0 ; $i<$table_count; ++$i)             
    {
        $qry6 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chairpulling_info WHERE table_id = '$table_id[$i]'");
        $row6 = mysql_fetch_array($qry6);
        $chairs_can_pullfrom[$i] = $row6['chairs_can_pullfrom'];        
    }
```

**so now the input will be like this**

```
$chairs_can_pullfrom[0] = 1,2 ;
$chairs_can_pullfrom[1] = 3,2,5;
$chairs_can_pullfrom[2] = 1,2,3;
```

The final output I'm looking for is

```
$result = 5 
$result_2 = 1,2,3,5
```

$result is unique values and $result_2 merge all value and  is avoid repetition.

Comment: Why the `$result` is 5? I think it should be 4 if it's numbers of unique values.

Comment: @MinhNguyen in this inputs 1 , 2 , 3 are repeated in other one but 5 didnt repeat so i need to store it on another variable/

Answer (score 0):

Please use array_mearge and then array_unique

```
<?php 

$newArray = array_merge($chairs_can_pullfrom[0], $chairs_can_pullfrom[1], $chairs_can_pullfrom[2]);

$result =  array_unique($newArray);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `$chairs_can_pullfrom[0]`, `$chairs_can_pullfrom[1]`, `$chairs_can_pullfrom[2]` are arrays:

```
$allvalues     = array_merge($chairs_can_pullfrom[0], $chairs_can_pullfrom[1], $chairs_can_pullfrom[2]);
$unique_values = array_unique($allvalues);
$count_values  = array_count_values($allvalues);
$unique        = array_filter($allvalues, function($var) use ($count_values){
    return $count_values[$var] === 1;
});
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/M8RM90)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my testing code.

```
<?php
$chairs_can_pullfrom[0] = array(1, 2);
$chairs_can_pullfrom[1] = array(3,2,5);
$chairs_can_pullfrom[2] = array(1,2,3);

$tmp = array();

$result = array();
$result_2 = array();

foreach($chairs_can_pullfrom as $chairs){
    foreach($chairs as $chair){
        if(!array_key_exists($chair, $tmp)){
            $tmp[$chair] = 1;
        }
        else {
            $tmp[$chair]++;
        }
    }
}

foreach($tmp as $key => $value){
    if($value == 1){
        $result[] = $key;
    }
    $result_2[] = $key;
}

var_dump($result, $result_2);
?>
```